# I am trying to run a 360 video on asp.net core using aframe but video is not loading

Tags: html, aframe

So I am tryin to mimic the [website](https://aframe.io/aframe/examples/boilerplate/360-video/) for my project. I am running this file on ASP.net Core. But all its showing is Black screen with a text "Click or tap to start video".
[image]
This is the following code in my razor view.

```
<html>
  <head>
      <script src="https://aframe.io/releases/1.2.0/aframe.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <a-scene inspector="" keyboard-shortcuts="" screenshot="" vr-mode-ui="" device-orientation-permission-ui="">
            <a-assets>
                
                <video id="video" autoplay="" loop="" crossorigin="anonymous" playsinline="" webkit-playsinline="" src="https://bitmovin.com/player-content/playhouse-vr/progressive.mp4">
                </video>
            </a-assets>
            <a-videosphere rotation="0 -90 0" src="#video" play-on-click="" material="" geometry="" scale="">
            </a-videosphere>
            <a-camera camera="" position="" rotation="" look-controls="" wasd-controls="">
                <a-entity position="0 0 -1.5" text="align:center;
                                                    width:6;
                                                    wrapCount:100;
                                                    color: white;
                                                    value: Click or tap to start video" hide-on-play="#video">
                </a-entity>
            </a-camera>
            </a-scene>
        
        
        <div id="highlighter--hover-tools" style="display: none;">
            <div id="highlighter--hover-tools--container">
                <div class="highlighter--icon highlighter--icon-copy" title="Copy"></div>
                <div class="highlighter--separator"></div>
                <div class="highlighter--icon highlighter--icon-change-color" title="Change Color"></div>
                <div class="highlighter--separator"></div>
                <div class="highlighter--icon highlighter--icon-delete" title="Delete"></div>
            </div>
        </div></body>
</html>
```

I have also checked my console in chrome, even it doesn't show any error.

So in my console it is showing : `core:a-assets:warn Asset loading timed out in   3000 ms` but I've already using this aframe.js in my head before using it in my body. Then why it's still showing it.
[image]

Comment: I am new to aframe js. Do you have any idea why is it showing so? Because one time it  worked fine but now its showing this.

Comment: I don't understand why its failing because I have added aframe.js in my head before actually using it in body.

Comment: sorry for the long reply, did you manage to make it work, or You need help?